# Need help with discrete math question

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Hey I was wondering if someone could do this question for me I have several such questions and I am completely lost.

A Board of Directors panel consist of one president, one vice-president, one secretary, one treasurer, and a three-person party committee. The entire board consists of seven distinct directors. If there are $n \geq 7$ applicants, how many ways are there to choose a Board of Directors? Justify
your answer.

Comment: We can apply the principle of multiplication. First choose the 7 person board out of $n$ applicants (how many ways are there?). Then, from these 7 people, choose the president (how many ways are there?). Then choose the vice-president (how many ways left to choose him/her?). Continue with the treasurer. Multiply the answer from each part to get the overall number of ways.

Comment: ohh makes sense so would it be n*n*n*n*(n*(n-1)*(n-2))? @KelvinSoh

Comment: Not quite yet. But the idea is along the right track. I'd type it out as an answer (you will need the concept of the combination $n \choose{r}$ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination if you haven't encountered it already

Answer (score 2):

There are $n \choose 7$ ways to choose the board. Notice that the 7 people are already picked out. Hence there are 7 ways to choose the president. Now that the president is chosen, we only have 6 ways left to choose the vice-president, and then 5 ways for the treasurer and 4 for the secretary.

Thus the answer will be ${n\choose 7} \times 7 \times 6 \times 5 \times 4$.

P.S. One "fun" aspect of combinatorics is there are many ways to solve the same question. Are you able to come up with others? (e.g. Let's not choose the entire board first. Maybe we can start somewhere else to assemble the board?)

Comment: what about the three man party committee? @KelvinSoh

Comment: My bad. I forgot about the secretary. Have made the change. After we are done choosing the 4 key positions, the remaining 3 (from our group of 7) will automatically become the three man party committee so we need not consider them (or, there is only 1 way to choose them after we have done the previous parts so we multiply by 1)

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 named positions and 3 person committee. So the answer depends on if you care about the order the committee is picked. That is if you see the committee Ann, Bob and Chloe as being the same as Bob, Chloe and Ann.  If you don't (order is important) then its just

$$n \times (n-1) \times (n-2) \times (n-3)\times (n-4)\times (n-5)\times (n-6)$$

If you only care who is in the committee then it's

$$\frac{n \times (n-1) \times (n-2) \times (n-3)\times (n-4)\times (n-5)\times (n-6)}{3 \times 2 \times 1}$$

---

The way this is calculated is that if we pick 7 people from a pool of $n$ and we care about the order then the first person can be any of the $n$ people, the second can be any of the $(n-1)$ people remaining, the third any of the $(n-2)$ and so on.

This makes the number of possible arrangements is:  $n \times (n-1) \times (n-2) \times (n-3)\times (n-4)\times (n-5)\times (n-6)$

But if we only care about who is on the committee and not the order we can arrange the committee $3 \times 2 \times 1 = 6$ ways.  So we divide the number by six to get the answer above.

---

Also Note ${n\choose 7} = ^{n}C_r = \frac{n!}{(n-r)!r!}$

So ${n\choose 7}\times 7 \times 6 \times 5 \times 4 = \frac{n!}{(n-7)!7!} \times 7 \times 6 \times 5 \times 4 = \frac{n!}{(n-7)!7!} \cdot \frac{7!}{3!}$

Which if you extend it is equivalent to my equation above.  Both answers are correct but doing it my way you avoid having to calculate large intermediate values.

Comment: I am soo confused now who is right?

Comment: @james both answers are correct I've edited my answer to explain why.

Comment: @james To try and avoid any confusion My answer finds how many permutations you can get of 7 people from n then divides by how many ways you can order 3 as we only care who is in the committee. Kevin's answer finds how many combinations there are of 7 from n times the number of ways you can pick 4 named positions from there. Christian's answer finds the number of ways you can pick 4 named people times the number of combinations of 3 people there are from the remaining $(n-4)$.  All 3 are correct.  Please accept the answer you find most convincing

Answer (score 0):

There are $n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)$ ways to choose a president, a vice-president, a secretary, and a treasurer in turn from $n$ applicants. Whatever your choice, there are $n-4$ applicants left, from which you can choose three more members of the board in ${n-4\choose 3}$ ways. It follows that the whole board can be chosen in 
$$N=n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3){n-4\choose 3}$$
ways.